# dyld[9429]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib

Tags: npm, homebrew, hadoop-yarn

I find issue in bellow, how to fix it?

$ yarn start                                                                                               ‹ruby-2.7.6›
dyld[9429]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib
Referenced from: <06DCAF44-526A-3E1E-8FF5-DD30A0E56B0C> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.8.1/bin/node
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    9429 abort      yarn start

i try this, but still error

```
$ brew info icu4c                                                                                          ‹ruby-2.7.6›
==> icu4c: stable 73.2 (bottled) [keg-only]
C/C++ and Java libraries for Unicode and globalization
https://icu.unicode.org/home
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2 (268 files, 80.1MB)
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-06-20 at 18:45:02
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/icu4c.rb
License: ICU
==> Caveats
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include"

For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
==> Analytics
install: 115,177 (30 days), 364,590 (90 days), 364,590 (365 days)
install-on-request: 6,336 (30 days), 6,336 (90 days), 6,336 (365 days)
build-error: 23 (30 days)

~/Desktop/react-native/omsetku-react-native-dev on  fix/feedback-issue-41! ⌚ 7:33:48
$  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc                                      ‹ruby-2.7.6›

~/Desktop/react-native/omsetku-react-native-dev on  fix/feedback-issue-41! ⌚ 7:34:05
$ echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc                                      ‹ruby-2.7.6›

~/Desktop/react-native/omsetku-react-native-dev on  fix/feedback-issue-41! ⌚ 7:34:10
$ yarn start                                                                                               ‹ruby-2.7.6›
dyld[9842]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib
  Referenced from: <06DCAF44-526A-3E1E-8FF5-DD30A0E56B0C> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.8.1/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/73.2/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.72.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    9842 abort      yarn start
```

[issue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x3cr.png)
but this fix with action

```
$ brew upgrade npm
```

[fix issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxuGK.png)
and now can run yarn
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dKbi.png)
so, Hopefully it can help you in solving this issue

Answer (score 6):

`brew reinstall icu4c` works for me.